# It requires Enterprise Edition (64-bit) or higher

Tags: ssis

I'm running a SQL 2012 Standard Edition and Visual Studio 2010 within a Virtual Server and I'm running a Package via SQL Server Job and I get the following error:

06/17/2014 16:35:57,A_E,Error,,X,A_E,,,The job failed.  The Job was invoked by Schedule 17 (A_E).  The last step to run was step 1 (A_E).,00:00:19,0,0,,,,0
06/17/2014 16:35:57,A_E,Error,1,X,A_E,A_E,,Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  16:35:57  Error: 2014-06-17 16:36:15.87     Code: 0xC00470FE     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: The Fuzzy Lookup cannot run on the installed edition of Integration Services. It requires Enterprise Edition (64-bit) or higher.  End Error  Error: 2014-06-17 16:36:15.87     Code: 0xC00470FE     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: The Fuzzy Lookup 1 cannot run on the installed edition of Integration Services. It requires Enterprise Edition (64-bit) or higher.  End Error  Error: 2014-06-17 16:36:15.87     Code: 0xC00470FE     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: The Fuzzy Lookup 2 cannot run on the installed edition of Integration Services. It requires Enterprise Edition (64-bit) or higher.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  16:35:57  Finished: 16:36:15  Elapsed:  18.236 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.,00:00:19,0,0,,,,0

The Package runs fine in BIDS but when I remove the Fuzzy lookup from the package the package works via SQL Server Job I don't get the error above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below transformations are supported only by Enterprise edition.

- Persistent (high performance) lookups
- Data mining query transformation
- Fuzzy grouping and lookup transformations
- Term extractions and lookup transformations

You can build and test an SSIS package using Enterprise-Edition-only components, but you cannot execute this package outside the SQL Server Data Tools environment.

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc645993.aspx#SSIS) official SQL server edition comparison article. Have a look of [this thread](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2012/04/18/an-important-consideration-for-ssis-and-sql-server-2012-business-intelligence-edition.aspx) as well.

Comment: Does this mean I will have to upgrade the Management Studio and Visual Studio to Enterprise Edition?

Comment: Nop, it's nothing to do with SSMS or BIDS/SSDT, these are just development environment. Basically this is with product licensing.  You have to upgrade your Standard edition to Enterprise or buy enterprise edition.